# Nested Menu CSS Hover Fade

Tags: html, css

I modified [this menu](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/) and added css [opacity hover transition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/6806643).

It only works on the first `ul`, but the nested sub `ul`'s will not show.
https://jsfiddle.net/sh73vvgf/

Replacing the fade effect with `display: none;` will show the sub menus.
https://jsfiddle.net/v8op2tqv/

How can I get fade to work on the sub menus? I need it to be pure html/css.

**HTML**

This nested menu shows a list of Planets and their Moons.

```
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Planets
      <ul>
        <li>
          Jupiter
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Europa
            </li>
            <li>
              Ganymede
            </li>
            <li>
              Callisto
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Saturn
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Mimas
            </li>
            <li>
              Dione
            </li>
            <li>
              Titan
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Uranus
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Umbriel
            </li>
            <li>
              Ariel
            </li>
            <li>
              Oberon
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-main ul {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-main ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-width: 25%;
  padding: 0.3em;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Hover Fade */
.nav-main li ul { 
  webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, transform 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-main li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-main li:hover li { 
    float: none; 
}

.nav-main ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-main ul:before,
.nav-main ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.nav-main ul:after { 
    clear: both; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some "overflow" style of your code.

```css
.nav-main ul {
  cursor: default;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nav-main ul:hover {
  overflow:visible;
}

.nav-main ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-width: 25%;
  padding: 0.3em;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav-main ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Hover Fade */
.nav-main li ul { 
  webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out, transform 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  //overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-main li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-main li:hover li { 
    float: none; 
}

.nav-main ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-main ul:before,
.nav-main ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.nav-main ul:after { 
    clear: both; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Planets
      <ul>
        <li>
          Jupiter
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Europa
            </li>
            <li>
              Ganymede
            </li>
            <li>
              Callisto
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Saturn
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Mimas
            </li>
            <li>
              Dione
            </li>
            <li>
              Titan
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Uranus
          <!-- Moons -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              Umbriel
            </li>
            <li>
              Ariel
            </li>
            <li>
              Oberon
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. On the full site menu instead of removing overflow, I actually had to use overflow: hidden; on the ul, and overflow: visible; on the :hover because it was stretching the menu height.